# Google Sheets time function in statistics

Tags: datetime, filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

My team uses Google Sheets to gather statistic data about users of the website. I got a function to sort different types of info with `COUNTIFS`. I need 2 types of time function. First is to gather this data from sheet only from the current date

[image: 0]

And the second function is to mark Date that we need to do (current date -3 days)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rn03GQfde0V6L39epOf9KiBrw9k2uRNNlcsDC7jjh8M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rn03GQfde0V6L39epOf9KiBrw9k2uRNNlcsDC7jjh8M/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### between two dates it would be:

```
=COUNTIFS($D2:$D; K4; 
          $B2:$B; $J4; 
          $A2:$A; ">="&DATE(2019; 8; 1); 
          $A2:$A; "<="&DATE(2020; 8; 1))
```

[image: 0]

---

#### between current day minus 3 days it would be:

```
=COUNTIFS($D2:$D; L4; 
          $B2:$B; $J4; 
          $A2:$A; ">="&TODAY()-3; 
          $A2:$A; "<="&TODAY())
```

[image: 0]